# Cannot convert from 'void *' to 'node *'

Tags: c, malloc

I am having a problem with my code to convert from 'void *' to 'NODE *'

Can anyone help me get around this problem?

```
NODE *list_create(void *data)
{
NODE *node;
if(!(node = malloc(sizeof(NODE)))) return NULL;
node->data=data;
node->next=NULL;
return node;
}
```

I get the error right underneath the = sign. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the error? May be you are using a C++ compiler instead of a C compiler.

Comment: No C compiler would complain about the absence of a cast in the assignment; every C++ compiler would complain about the absence of a cast in the assignment. Therefore, you should start compiling your code with a C compiler, not with a C++ compiler, because you will be confused every time the compiler complains about something that is legitimate in C but illegitimate in C++.  Using the wrong compiler is a serious problem.  (Are you working on Windows, perchance?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not specified the error, but assuming from the looks of the code, most probable is the type conversion error, something like:

> Cannot convert void* to NODE*

The question is tagged with `C` and the code written here is also valid `C`, but invalid `C++`. So if there is an error, it can be safely assumed that a C++ compiler is being used to compile the code.

To remove the error, either use a C compiler; or if you want to stick with a C++ compiler, explicitly type cast the return value of `malloc`.

```
if(!(node = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE)))) return NULL;
```

Comment: If you're using a C++ compiler, it would be better to stick to writing C++ code, using native C++ idioms.  Although C++ does support `malloc()`, it is not the normal way of allocating memory in C++ — you should be using `new` and `new[]` and related idioms.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler... Yes, I would also recommend using `new` instead of `malloc`, but I wanted to stay close to OP's code.

Comment: That made the error go away. Thank you. As for using a C compiler I am just using Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express. It was free from Microsoft.. Is there a different program that is free that is for just C?

Comment: @mebrunner24... You can use Visual C++ as a `C++` compiler as well as a pure `C 89` compiler. Just go to `Project Properties` -> `C/C++` -> `Advanced` -> `Compile As`->`C`.

Comment: Will that automatically be set every time I open it? I am curious because I can never get a program to run correctly unless I go to Project -> Project Properties -> Linker -> General and change the Enable Incremental Linking to NO (/INCREMENTAL:NO).. Would changing it to a C compiler get rid of this annoying error as well?

Comment: @mebrunner24... No this setting has nothing to do with linker. Once you select the compiler, it will be saved permanently for the project until you change it. I cannot say anything about the linker problem you are having.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!(node = malloc(sizeof(NODE)))) return NULL;
```

`malloc` returns a `void` pointer (as it doesn't know what you want to do with the memory you've requested.

The compiler is trying to figure out why you want the memory. Cast it to a `(NODE *)` to give it a hint