# C2440 error when using malloc c++

Tags: c++

i was trying the code of  "KEYVIEW1.C − Charles Petzold, 1998 " in visual studio but i encountered an error by this part of the code:

`pmsg =(void*) malloc(cLinesMax * sizeof (MSG));`

the error is :

> Error 1   error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'void *' to
>   'PMSG'    d:\win32
>   projects\win32project8\win32project8\win32project8.cpp    97  1   Win32Project8

can any one help me solving this problem ?

Comment: Why would you use `malloc` in C++????

Comment: Why are you casting to `void*` instead of `PMSG`?

Comment: Try:   pmsg =(MSG*) malloc(cLinesMax * sizeof (MSG));

Comment: 1. Don't use malloc in c++. Why would you? 2. The error is written right there in the error message.

Comment: In C++ explicit typecasting is required (MSG*). In C this would have worked.

Comment: That books is about C, WinAPI and Windows programming. Very little to do with the C++.

Comment: @Raw N: right, but ehy, that book is 19 years old, and anyway title, tags and source code filename explicitely state "c++", so we answer for C++ ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The error is caused by `(void *)malloc(..)`.
`malloc()` doesn't know your variable type (`MSG *`) so it returns a typeless pointer (`void *`).
Now you want to set a `MSG *` to a `void *` and that's where the error happens.
`MSG *` and `void *` obviously aren't the same types.

**Don't use `malloc()` in c++:** [Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/184540/3206306), [Why?](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/6555/to-new-is-c-to-malloc-is-c-to-mix-them-is-sin)

**Code examples:**
If you still want to use `malloc()`, here is how:

```
MSG *pmsg = (MSG *)malloc(cLinesMax * sizeof(MSG)); // Allocate Memory
... pmsg[0].member = "blub";    // Do stuff with pmsg
free( pmsg );                   // Delete dynamic allocated memory
```

If you want to use the c++-way, here is how:

```
MSG *pmsg = new MSG[cLinesMax]; // Allocate an Array of MSG's with size $cLinesMax
... pmsg[0].member = "blub";    // Do stuff with pmsg
delete[] pmsg;                  // Delete dynamic allocated memory
```

The c++-way is more readable in my opinion and `new` and `delete` are safer than `malloc` and `free`.

Clarification example: http://ideone.com/46twoD

In fact: *YOU* make less errors with `new` and `delete`!

1. `malloc()` returns `void *`
   *You* have to cast it to `MSG *` *yourself*.
   `new` casts it for you
2. `malloc()` takes bytes count as an argument, which means
   *You* have to calculate bytes count *yourself* (`num * sizeof(MSG)`).
   *You* can miscalculate the bytes count (e.g. `sizeof(MSG)` vs `sizeof(MSG *)`)
   `new` automatically calculates bytes count for you

Answer (score 1):

**Suggestion**
DO NOT use malloc() in C++ programs, prefer using `new` or, even better [RAII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) techniques.

If you are still forced to use malloc() for whatever reason, you have to cast the void* returned by malloc() to the receiving variable pointer type, in your case probably:

```
pmsg = (MSG*)malloc(cLinesMax * sizeof(MSG));
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove the error, either use a C compiler; or if you want to stick with a C++ compiler, then you need to explicitly type cast the return value of malloc.

Similar problem is resolved here: [Cannot convert from 'void *' to 'node *'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20020173/cannot-convert-from-void-to-node)

Comment: You are compiling this program using C++ compiler, and C++ supports malloc function. But this is not the good way of allocating memory in C++, here you should use new operator. To remove the error you should do a  explicit type cast like "(MSG*)malloc(cLinesMax * sizeof(MSG));"